Proving the least upper bound theorem/supremums axiom from the half line theorem

Theorem 2.13 (Least Upper Bound Theorem)
Let $X$ be a non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that has upper bounds. Then among the upper bounds for $X$ there is a smallest one.
Proof: Let $L$ be the set of all numbers that are not upper bounds for $X$. Trivially $L \neq \mathbb{R}$ . For any $x \in X$, we have $x-1 \in L$ , so $ L \neq \phi$ . It is obvious that $L$ satisfies the requirements for the half line theorem to be applied. Hence, there is a number $C$ WITH $L=(-\infty,c)$ or $L=(-\infty,c]$. The first case is trivial, clearly $c$ is smallest uper bound. In the second case, the numbers $c+1,c+\frac12, c+\frac13 ... $ are upper bounds for $X$ ; so is $c$ itself. This means that the second case does not really occur.
Topological Spaces: From Distance to Neighborhood by Buskes und Rooij.

I sort of understand why we define $L$. If we have a set like $(1,2)$ it's sort of easy to prove that supremum is $2$, from the definition of the set directly,. But, if we had something like $\{1-\frac1n| n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ we have to be more careful. Hence, we would want a set which is in some sense like an interval.
My question is, why is the second case more tricky that is, when $L$ is of form $(-\infty,c]$?

Please do not post duplicated questions

@Angelo I suggest you reread the question

Thank you for your thoughtful suggestion, but, as I have explained to you already, if you were to read the post, then you would realize it is not a duplicate. @Angelo

I suggested you delete your duplicated post just because I had read it before.

How is it possible that a question which asks about proof of the supremums theorem and a question which asks about application of supremums theorem are the same? @Angelo

It is absolutely possible because they are very similar and the proof is that your post was closed which means that I am not the only person who thinks that your post is a duplicated.
